# Label of CorePlot Chart not displayed in the graph after deploying in App Store (iPhone)

Tags: ios, app-store, core-plot, label, bar-chart

The labels of the CorePlot Chart are displayed properly when deploying the application directly on to the iPhone. Whereas, the labels do not appear when downloading the application from the App store.

The application seems to be working fine until its been converted to binary file and deployed in App store.

Anyone who knows what's the issue with the labels, Kindly help us.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This should work properly on appstore. Make sure the binary you uploaded to appstore is properly archived.